# Installation issue in sproutcore

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sproutcore

I was installing Sproutcore while installation I was facing issue saying that "Error installing Sproutecore: The 'http_parser.rb' native gem requires installed build tools. Please update your PATH to include build tool...".

Check below screenshot of my command prompt.

[image]

I thought this error generate because I didn't set ruby path in environment variable but after setting up path I am facing same error. Please advise.

I follow this [link](http://www.tribloom.com/blogs/michael/2011/04/01/sproutcore-installation-from-the-ground-up) to install sproutcore.

Comment: Did you install the DevKit also like the instructions say?

Comment: No, i only installed ruby. I don't know how to install it.

Comment: See the text in the chapter titled "SproutCore" in the instructions. You need to install the DevKit also.

Comment: Actually I take that comment back. Later down the instructions it says to do this instead: `gem install eventmachine --pre`. Anyway, why am I reading the instructions and not you? :)

Comment: @Casper Thank you for instruction, i download that DevKit but it's documentation is so confusing. If you have better documentation then please share with me.

Comment: Eventmachine was successfully install in my case even though i applied that code after success message i again tried to install sproutcore but getting same error. So for full and final solution i have to install DevKit only. Just asking again for surety.

Comment: Ok. It looks like http_parser.rb is not directly supported by Ruby 2.0 at the moment. Here are some discussions and instructions: https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb/issues/22   https://github.com/johanneswuerbach/http_parser.rb_2.0_precompiled  Sorry can't help more than that. Perhaps install Ruby 1.9 instead and try again if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for links, i already tried in Ruby 1.9 then i moved to Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install This DevKit:

https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe

after installation go to devkit dir and run this following command

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
```

Comment: Worked for me. Just had to struggle for appropriate versions of gem, ruby and DevKit. Thanks Wiram.